# laravel 4 , NotFoundHttpException

Tags: laravel-4

i have problem in submitting this form  it produces NotFoundHttpException

```
{{Form::open(array('parsley-validate'=>'','url'=>url('dashboard/send_message')))}}
```

this is the function the form should execute in dashHome.php in dashboard folder

```
public function postSendMessage()
{
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
        'studentId' => 'required|exists:student,id',
        'content' => 'required',
        ));

    if ($validator->fails())
        return Redirect::to('dashboard')->withErrors($validator);

    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->decrement('sms_credit');

    return Redirect::to('dashboard')->with('messageSent',1);
}
```

this is the route in  route.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dashboard','before'=>'auth'), function() {

Route::get('/', 'dashHome@index');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a route for the url `dashboard/send_message` in your `routes.php` file, like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'dashboard','before'=>'auth'), function() 
{
    Route::get('/', 'dashHome@index');
    Route::post('send_message', 'dashHome@postSendMessage');
});
```